# I can't autorize in forge.autodesk.com

Tags: autodesk-forge

I have completed registration, but after each login attempt, I am redirected to the following page.

[image]

When I fill in the required fields and click "sumbit", I am redirected to the following page again.
I've tried to create a new account, but I still have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly:

1. You go to https://forge.autodesk.com
2. You click the "Sign In" button in the top-right corner, and log in with your account
3. You are redirected to the "Welcome, Danila!" page

It sounds like your browser (it's cookies) might be stuck in some process that's supposed to get more information about yourself. Please try one of the following:

- Go to https://forge.autodesk.com using a different web browser, and try logging in there
- Clear the cookies for the forge.autodesk.com website in your current browser (for example, [here's how you can do that in Google Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95647?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en-GB)), and try logging in again

And if you're still having troubles, please contact us via `forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com`, and we'll take it from there.